# Nand To Tetris (Jack): Simple if conditional with equality testing giving this error - "Expected - or ~ or ( in term"

Tags: nand2tetris

```
class Main {
  function void main() {
    var String foo;
    let foo = "bar";

    if (foo == "bar") {
      do Output.printString("true");
    }
    else {
      do Output.printString("false");
    }

    return;
  }
}
```

I get the error: `Expected - or ~ or ( in term`.

Full output:

```
code/nand2tetris » tools/JackCompiler.sh projects/09/Test
Compiling /Users/adamzerner/code/nand2tetris/projects/09/Test
In Main.jack (line 6): In subroutine main: Expected - or ~ or ( in term
code/nand2tetris »
```

What does the error mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I used `==` instead of `=`. In Jack, equality is tested for using a single equals rather than a double or triple (double/triple equals is conventional in other languages).

See bullet point 7 in slide 22 of the [Chapter 9 PDF](http://www.nand2tetris.org/lectures/PDF/lecture%2009%20high%20level%20language.pdf) for documentation saying that equality comparison is done with a single equals.

See `SquareGame.jack` line 40 in the course software for an example.

The following code compiles without error. It doesn't give the expected output, but the reason for that is a separate topic.

```
class Main {
  function void main() {
    var String foo;
    let foo = "bar";

    if (foo = "bar") {
      do Output.printString("true");
    }
    else {
      do Output.printString("false");
    }

    return;
  }
}
```