# Nand to Tetris: string equality test isn't working

Tags: nand2tetris

This is outputting `false` instead of `true`. Why is this?

```
class Main {
  function void main() {
    var String foo;
    let foo = "bar";

    if (foo = "bar") {
      do Output.printString("true");
    }
    else {
      do Output.printString("false");
    }

    return;
  }
}
```

I suspect it's because `foo` and `"bar"` are each objects, and the `=` tests whether the starting address of each object is the same ([note that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433103/nand-to-tetris-simple-if-conditional-with-equality-testing-giving-this-error) in Jack, equality is tested for with a single equals, rather than a double or triple equals). I haven't gotten to chapters 10/11 yet, which is when I'll discover whether or not this hypothesis is true.

Comment: I removed my previous answer again. If the single equal sign is valid, then you're assumption seems to correct, that there are two representations for strings.

Comment: @OliverHader ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer, but here it comes. Your program will dynamically create a string on the heap for every occurrence of "bar" and your code will compare two distinct addresses on the heap. The comparison will be false.

How do I know that? I have just finished writing the compiler...